# Sending ICS as Mail Attachment using memorystream

Tags: c#

I am creating a ics file in my controller. Using asp.net core 2.0 mvc. I now have the content and everything done and I can send the ics file as a mail attachment. But I dont want to create a file locally on my pc, I want to use memorystream or something without a physical path.

This is how im creating the ics content:

```
string schLocation = "Nord 1";
            string schSubject = "Badge-Austausch";
            string schDescription = "Termin zum Austauschen des Badges";
            System.DateTime schBeginDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateOwnRegister);
            System.DateTime schEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(schBeginDate.AddMinutes(30));
            string[] contents = { "BEGIN:VCALENDAR",
                               "PRODID:-//Flo Inc.//FloSoft//EN",
                               "BEGIN:VEVENT",
                               "DTSTART:" + schBeginDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd\\THHmmss\\Z"),
                               "DTEND:" + schEndDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd\\THHmmss\\Z"),
                               "LOCATION:" + schLocation,
                          "DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:" + schDescription,
                               "SUMMARY:" + schSubject, "PRIORITY:3",
                          "END:VEVENT", "END:VCALENDAR"
```

This is how Ive been trying to use the memorystream:

```
char[] charArray = contents.SelectMany(x => x.ToCharArray()).ToArray();
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(charArray);
            System.IO.MemoryStream mStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(charArray));
            System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ms);
            writer.Write(byteArray);
```

And this is how i send it as attachment. The sending works but i cant open the file in outlook. So it doesnt work as a calendar invitation;

```
System.Net.Mime.ContentType contype = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
                System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, contype);
                attach.ContentDisposition.FileName = "myFile.ics";
                msg.Attachments.Add(attach);
                sc.Send(msg);
```

Happy about any ideas or solutions on how I could get this to work. As I said the "contents" worked when I sent the file from my local data but the sending without local paths didnt work yet.

Comment: Might be that you don’t rewind the memorystream so it points to the end?

Comment: got the issue fixed anyways but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work using string builder.

````
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var line in contents)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(line);

            }
            var calendarBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
            MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream(calendarBytes);
            System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(memorystream, "event.ics", "text/calendar");```
````